# Exception trying to get folder in MailKit, but not when enumerating folders first

Tags: c#, imap, mailkit

I'm using MaikKit, and am trying to work out how to get the mail in a `Jim` folder I set up in a Gmail account. I tried enumerating the folders as follows...

```cs
    private void GetFolders() {
      using ImapClient client = new();
      EmailAccount emailAccount = EmailAccountOptions.Value;
      client.Connect(emailAccount.Server, emailAccount.Port, SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect);
      client.Authenticate(emailAccount.UserName, emailAccount.Password);

      foreach (FolderNamespace ns in client.PersonalNamespaces) {
        IMailFolder folder = client.GetFolder(ns);
        _msg += $"<br/>Ns: {ns.Path} / {folder.FullName}";
        foreach (IMailFolder subfolder in folder.GetSubfolders()) {
          _msg += $"<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp; {subfolder.FullName}";
        }
      }

      try {
        IMailFolder jim = client.GetFolder(new FolderNamespace('/', "Jim"));
        jim.Open(FolderAccess.ReadOnly);
        _msg += $"<br/>Got Jim, has {jim.Count} email(s)";
      }
      catch (Exception ex) {
        _msg += $"<br/>Ex ({ex.GetType()}): {ex.Message}";
      }
    }
```

This shows the following...

```
Ns: /
   INBOX
   Jim
   [Gmail]
   ✔
   ✔✔
Got Jim, has 1 email(s)
```

So, it seems I can access `Jim` without problem. As the purpose of this was to access `Jim` only, the enumeration isn't needed. However, when I removed it, I got an exception...

```
Ns: /
Ex (MailKit.FolderNotFoundException): The requested folder could not be found
```

After some trial and error, I found out that the following works...

```cs
private void GetFolders() {
  using ImapClient client = new();
  EmailAccount emailAccount = EmailAccountOptions.Value;
  client.Connect(emailAccount.Server, emailAccount.Port, SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect);
  client.Authenticate(emailAccount.UserName, emailAccount.Password);

  foreach (FolderNamespace ns in client.PersonalNamespaces) {
    IMailFolder folder = client.GetFolder(ns);
    var subs = folder.GetSubfolders();
  }

  try {
    IMailFolder jim = client.GetFolder(new FolderNamespace('/', "Jim"));
    jim.Open(FolderAccess.ReadOnly);
    _msg += $"<br/>Got Jim, has {jim.Count} email(s)";
  }
  catch (Exception ex) {
    _msg += $"<br/>Ex ({ex.GetType()}): {ex.Message}";
  }
}
```

...but if I remove the call to `folder.GetSubfolders()` it throws an exception.

If I change the code to look for `INBOX` instead...

```
IMailFolder jim = client.GetFolder(new FolderNamespace('/', "INBOX"));
```

...then it works fine even without the call to `folder.GetSubfolders()`.

Anyone any idea why this happens? As far as I can see, the `foreach` loop isn't doing anything that should affect `Jim`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just so it's clear, using `ImapClient.GetFolder (FolderNamespace)` the way you are using it is not the correct way of using that API.

A few general API rules to consider when using MailKit:

1. **All** APIs that require network I/O take a `CancellationToken` argument. So if a *Client or *Folder API doesn't take a `CancellationToken`, that means it's a cache lookup or something else that doesn't require hitting the network.
2. MailKit APIs don't require you to call a constructor just to pass a string to the method ;-)

With the `ImapClient.GetFolder(FolderNamespace)` API, there is an equivalent `ImapFolder.GetFolder(string path, CancellationToken)` API that is meant to be used for such tasks.

(Note: The only reason that the `FolderNamespace` .ctor is public is because someone out there may want to implement the MailKit `IMailStore` or `IImapClient` interfaces and will need to be able to create `FolderNamespace` instances).

That said, I am loathe to recommend this API because MailKit's `ImapFolder` was designed to get folders 1 level at a time via the `ImapFolder.GetSubfolders()` and/or `ImapFolder.GetSubfolder()` APIs and so the `ImapClient.GetFolder()` API is a huge hack that has to recursively fetch folder paths and string them together.

Keep in mind that `ImapFolder` instances have a `ParentFolder` property that the MailKit API guarantees will always be set.

That makes things difficult to guarantee if the developer can just request rando folders anywhere in the tree at the `ImapClient` level using a full path.

Anyway... yea, the `Imapclient.GetFolder (string path, CancellationToken)` API exists and it works and you can use it if you want to, but let it be known that I hate that API.

**Okay, so now on to why your `client.GetFolder(new FolderNamespace(...))` hack doesn't work if you remove the call to `GetSubfolders()`**

As you've discovered, `IMailFolder jim = client.GetFolder(new FolderNamespace('/', "Jim"));` *only* works if a call such as `var subs = folder.GetSubfolders();` exists before it that happens to return the `/Jim` folder as one of the subfolders.

Your question is: *why?*

(or maybe your question is: *why doesn't it work without that line?*)

Either way, the answer is the same.

MailKit's ImapClient keeps a cache of known folders that exist in the IMAP folder tree so that it can quickly and easily find the parent of each folder and doesn't have to explicitly call `LIST` on each parent node in the path in order to build the `ImapFolder` chain (remmeber: each `ImapFolder` has a `ParentFolder` property that points to an `ImapFolder` instance that represents its direct parent all the way back up to the root).

So... that `GetSubfolders()` call is adding the `/Jim` folder to the cache.

Since the `GetFolder (new FolderNamesdpace ('/', "Jim"))` call cannot go out to the network, it relies on the internal cache. The only folders that exist in the cache after connecting are the folders that are returned in the `NAMESPACE` command and `INBOX`. Everything else gets added to the cache as they become known due to `LIST` responses (as a result of `GetSubfolders()` and `GetSubfolder()` calls).

Comment: Thanks very much for the great reply. At the moment (in code not shown here) I am getting the inbox and sent folders using `client.GetFolder(client.Inbox)` and `client.GetFolder(SpecialFolder.Sent)` respectively. Should I first use `client.PersonalNamespaces[0]` to get the ns, and then call `GetSubFolder` on that instead? Thanks again.

Comment: Hmm, just tried it and it seems I can't do it that way anyway. Please can you confirm if the way I'm accessing those two other folders is correct? Thanks again.

Comment: `client.GetFolder(client.Inbox)` doesn't make sense because `client.Inbox` is already an `ImapFolder` instance and as I mentioned in my answer, the `INBOX` folder is always cached immediately after authenticating, so it's always available. `client.GetFolder (SpecialFolder.Sent)` is also immediately cached after authenticating (if the server supports the `SPECIAL-USE` extension - which gmail does), so that is also a cache lookup and therefor doesn't need a `CancellationToken`.

Comment: I'm not sure what doesn't work for you, but maybe you are trying to get the Sent folder as a subfolder of Inbox? If so, that doesn't work because the Sent folder isn't a subfolder of the Inbox. You'd have to do: `var ns = client.GetFolder (client.PersonalNamespaces[0]); var gmail = ns.GetSubfolder ("[Gmail]"); var sent = gmail.GetSubfolder ("Sent");`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification